# Can I pass a string containing markdown to custom view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, markdown

I want to pass a string containing markdown to a custom view and have the formatting done in that view.

Example:

```
struct MyTest: View {
    let text: String // Some other type needed here
    
    init(_ text: String) { self.text = text }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
        Text("*Inline*")
    }
}
```

Use the view, eg.: `MyTest("*Test*")`

This will produce the output:

> *Test*
> *Inline*

The goal is to get the output:

> *Test*
> *Inline*

Is it possible to have the formatting passed to the `Text(text)` line in the custom view?

Comment: What is the relevance of `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation` here? I don't see any string interpolation in your example code? Do you mean you want `text` to be of some type conforming to `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation`?

Comment: Maybe I wrong regarding the protocol and that is only relevant in the case of `\(foo)`. But some magic is happening when the Text(...) handles the markdown formatted string (which is an `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`?).

Comment: Ah, no. `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` is not relevant to formatting markdown. It is only about `\(foo)`. So you just want to format markdown, right? I'll post an answer.

Comment: Yes, that is what I what! I'm looking forward to the answer! Thanks

Comment: And I'll rephrase the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting markdown "magic" comes from [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:tablename:bundle:comment:)) of `Text`, which takes a `LocalizedStringKey`. Since `LocalizedStringKey` conforms to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, `Text("*Inline*")` will call this initialiser, but `Text(someStringVariable)` will not.

So to format the markdown in the `text` property, you just need to call that initialiser. You can either make `text` a `LocalizedStringKey` itself:

```
struct MyTest: View {
    let text: LocalizedStringKey
    
    init(_ text: LocalizedStringKey) { self.text = text }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
        Text("*Inline*")
    }
}
```

Or create a `LocalizedStringKey` when creating the `Text`:

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey(text))
```

By using this initialiser of `Text`, you get the added benefit of localising the text! :D