# What Happened to NSAttributedString in Swift 5? Bold Doesnt work?

Tags: swift, swiftui, attributedstring

All the sample code i have comea cross with just does not work with bold tags anymore. This also include italic html tags.

I am using the code from hacking swift as string extension.

```
var htmlAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: Data(self.utf8), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            return attributedString
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var htmlString: String {
        return htmlAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
```

Then try

```
let string = "<b>sample</b>"
Text(string.htmlString)
```

The code looks about right. Just that the bold tag does not get rendered. Anyone know of a workaround? I tried the adding html style system hardcoding font trick but it did not work as well.

I tried the markdown alternative , no luck either (but this is a different topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your `htmlString` property essentially converts the attributed string back to a plain text string. Accessing the [`NSAttributedString.string`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1412616-string) property gives you the plain text parts of the string back, without any attributes.

Since this string is to be displayed in a `Text`, you can use the Swift [`AttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring) API instead. Change the type of `htmlAttributedString` to `AttributedString`, and convert the `NSAttributedString`:

```
extension String {
    var htmlAttributedString: AttributedString {
        if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: Data(self.utf8), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            return AttributedString(attributedString)
        }
        else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create the `Text` like this:

```
Text("<b>foo</b>bar".htmlAttributedString)
```

---

Side note: if you are working with markdown instead, you can directly create the `Text` using a string literal like this - no need for any `AttributedString`s

```
Text("**foo** bar")
```

If your markdown string is not a literal, wrap it in a `LocalizedStringKey`:

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey(someMarkdown))
```

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper I was focused on the return type of NSAttributedString that I used .string property so that Text() would accept it. I tried now and it works.

Comment: just an additional question if you have an idea. when rendered, the font size became too small compared to rendering it in plain text. Tried <big> but didnt work. Any idea of a workaround to make it bigger? Instead of. using font-size in style.

Comment: @chitgoks You can try adding a font attribute throughout the range of the whole string, before returning it in `htmlAttributedString`. But it seems like you are trying to display your own rich text instead of some random text on the web? If so, I recommend that you work with markdown instead - it works much more nicely with SwiftUI.

Comment: It seems that the default font is changed to helvetica with font size of 12 (normal behavior. I actually decided to use markdown first to avoid the hassle but even that didnt work out. I tried just Text("*test*") (removed double asterisk since it gets formatted here) but the same shows up, no formatting.

Comment: @chitgoks With markdown, you can change the font size and other things with the SwiftUI methods, like `.font(.largeTitle)`. `Text("**foo** bar")` works just fine for me. You can clearly see the distinction between the bold and the non-bold.

Comment: I agree. You are right. I think why it is not showing is because i am concatenating strings like let test = "**" + var1 + "** here is not bold anymore" but it did work when the full text with markdown are inside the string. Right now, I used a <span style=""> in my html string to make the font size bigger and override the default helvetica font that is being used.

Comment: @chitgoks Right, if you are doing that, wrap a `LocalizedStringKey` outside the markdown like my last code snippet. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71349993/5133585) for why.

Comment: I got it to work. Reason was i didnt use the markdown attribute he he he. My bad. Im going witht he markdown route instead of html. What a pain. But happy that I understand now. Thanks bud.

Comment: Text(LocalizedStringKey(someMarkdown)) information REALLY helped. Instead of fighting with AttributeString, I’m changing my string data. Thanks for this.